# cppcheck returns error even if no errors in stdout

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I run command like this:

```
./cppcheck file.cpp --inline-suppr --enable=all --error-exitcode=13 \
--quiet --suppress=missingInclude:* --suppress=unusedFunction:*  --inconclusive
```

There is nothing in stdout, but:

```
echo $?
13
```

At the same time, if I check other files, cppcheck writes nothing into stdout and returns 0:

```
echo $?
0
```

How can I understand, what is "wrong" with file.cpp?

Comment: What command did you use for the second example? You get 13 because of '--error-exitcode=13' in your first example.

Comment: @orbitcowboy, I use same command for all files. There are files for which cppcheck returns 13 and files for which cppcheck returns 0. At the same time there is nothing in stdout for all these files. I know about `--error-exitcode` - I want to use this specifically to distinguish  two cases: there are errors or not.

Comment: What version of cppcheck are you using? Could be related to this bug:
https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/5746

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in version 1.72, but having no issues in 1.52.

Answer (score 0):

My *cppcheck* version (with problem) is 1.82.

I haven't found exact problem (simple sample of code that reproduces the problem), but I have tried last version ('*Cppcheck 1.87 dev*' at the moment) and now the problem is solved (for me).

So, If you have same problem - try to upgrade *cppcheck*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how general this answer is, but maybe somebody might find it useful.

I got the same behavior in a third-party library header I had included with `-I`: cppcheck did not *show* the warning, but *did* count it for the exit code. Including it with `-isystem` instead made the problem go away.